# Best Practice to check session in ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, session

What is the best way to `check session` ?

Right now, my application is checking session in 2 places. One is Master Page_Load and aspx Page_Load and redirecting to `session` expire page.

Is it a good way to check `same session` two times ?

If not, can we check in `Page_Init` ?

Comment: This kind of stuff is usually best handled in Global.asax on BeginRequest event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use **BasePage**, and place command methods related to **Page**. Then inherit all pages from it. *I cannot say this is the best way.*

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["IsExpired"] == null)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```